# Under using a pc

Tags: physical-wear

I don't know if this is a good question or even if this is the right place to ask, but I was wondering if you were to have a good pc and under use it if it'll cause damage and if it'll cause damage can it be repaired without much money. Example being if say u only turned on the computer once a month or another example being that u have a mid range pc but you treat it like a cheap tablet. I imagine that a pc isn't really built for just watching YouTube or twitch. I know that internet activity is really low on pcs, it's like getting a college student to do 1+1 or simple math, while they should be doing Calais or something.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing on the PC that would be physically damaged by not turning it on or using it regularly. You might need to charge the battery (if it has one - it will drain slowly) and there will likely be updates available for the PC almost every time you turn it on if you don't use it regularly. You will want to be sure to install those updates especially if they're security related.

Comment: That's interesting but I wonder why a person in the modern area would buy a pc just to watch YouTube and Twitch, most people use phones and tablets to access the internet and I believe the consoles are 2nd, with pc being dead last. Does it bother you that the area of a pc in every home is dying?

Comment: @JoeyScranton PCs aren't really dying in any meaningful sense. Mobile and tablet market shares have grown, but PCs are currently still around 50%-60% of the US market in 2019 (laptop vs. desktop may be another debate). Furthermore, PCs broadly do a lot more than just provide videos online, etc. Mobile devices, tablets and consoles are easier and cheaper for simple entertainment/browsing, so it's hardly surprising that they are dominating "casual" internet usage. But ultimately they tend to be extremely lackluster at anything a "real" PC was made to do. Therefore, PCs are unlikely to go away.